# how to check for a condition in g select tag

Tags: grails, select, gsp

I'm a newbie to Grails and GSPs.
I need to achieve the following code using g:select tag

```
<select name="applaiances" style="width: 200px" onchange="selectedTC(this); ">
    <g:each in="${applaianceList}" var="appl">
       <g:if test="${appl == "TELEVISION"}">
          <option value="TELEVISION">TV</option>
       </g:if>
       <g:else>
          <option value="${appl}">${appl}</option>
       </g:else>
     </g:each>
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Vasanth, did this work for you? Please accept the answer if it did.

Comment: Would love to get credit for an accepted answer. You'll notice a tick mark below the vote down arrow. That's what you need to click to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried this in an app but you could try something like:

```
<g:select name="applaiances" onchange="selectedTC(this);" from="${applaianceList}" optionKey="${{it=='TELEVISION'?'TELEVISION':it}}" optionValue="${{it=='TELEVISION'?'TV':it}}"></g:select>
```

Not sure about the optionKey but you can apply transformation via a closure on the optionValue.

Update:
This is documented [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html). Just search for the phrase "If you require even more control over how each"